# Python 3 Default

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the package bayespy via the command line in enthought canopy. It does require me to run on python 3 however. I have downloaded and installed it but when I put

```
py -3
pip install bayespy
```

in the command prompt it still says I am not running on python 3. So how do I get it running on Python 3 to install bayespy?

Thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: Try `sudo python3 -m pip install bayespy`

Comment: It says 'sudo' is not an internal or external command, no combinations of this work

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: You can also try `pip3 install baysepy` instead of `pip install bayespy`.

Comment: Above does not work either, I am on windows

Comment: What about `python3 -m pip install bayespy` without the `sudo`. Or `python -m pip install bayespy`?

Comment: The later one ran but said I was running on python 2, not 3. Is there a simple way to set python 3 as my runner?

Comment: Check your environment variables and see if a path exists for Python 2. Delete that and replace it with Python 3.

Comment: I can't find the path for python 2 but for python 3 it is C:\Users\Max Kaye\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and I am on windows:

```
pip install bayespy
```

Do this without `py -3`

Good Luck!